# Animation with unintentional black boxes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, mesh, motion-capture

I'm making an Animation with a Motion Track. In my preview render everything is fine, but when I render my scene in png there are black boxes in some pictures.

At the beginning of the animation these dots (showing the cities) appear. After that the lines move towards the city Höxter. At the end a street sign is falling on the position where all lines are ending.

These black boxes just appear when the second animation is running. I don't have any other meshes in my scene that could create these black boxes or cast shadows on the map.

How can I fix it?

[image]

[image].

Heres the blend file:[image]

Comment: its hard to tell if you dont include the blend file, my assumption is that it has something to do with the red squares but not sure, things like that normally dont appear out of nothing. i wonder maybe some path deform effect on red cube .. and maybe things went wrong in setting that up.

Comment: How can I include the blend file? I'm new on this website: Please Tell me. I will do it directly...

Comment: please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for all blend files. (pasteall link only last for ~ six months)

Comment: One last question. Do you have the textures and the Video ( Motion Track) if you download the Blend.file ?

Comment: i've rendered it all, but i dont get the boxes...
could it be a problem with post operations (where you combine it all).

Comment: Ok, that's interesting. I probably just worked in blender. :/ Do you think installing blender again would help? Which version do you use ?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded my download file now, because user3800527 (thanks to you) told me, that its working on his pc. Now its working and there are no black boxes anymore. I can't tell exactly what the problem was. Maybe it just was a problem of blender.

Comment: Try some "debug" in your "glitchy" file. Press "~" button to enable all the layers, then press Alt + H (unhide all). It looks like some boxes were hidden, so they are invisible in the viewport, but still are visible on render.